# React checksum fails when using server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I build an isomorphic react app and some time a meta tag is not self closing on the server side, and i have the following invalid checksum error :

> You're trying to render a component to the document using server rendering but the checksum was invalid. This usually means you rendered a different component type or props on the client from the one on the server, or your render() methods are impure. React cannot handle this case due to cross-browser quirks by rendering at the document root. You should look for environment dependent code in your components and ensure the props are the same client and server side:

```
(client) -8" data-reactid="3"/><meta http-equiv="
(server) -8" data-reactid="3"><meta http-equiv="X
```

Is there a way to avoid this? any ideas ?

Comment: i'm having this issue now as well using React-Engine and React 15.4.0 on Heroku. The silly thing is I have other project running the exact same <head> code without errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the keys are identical (which they seem to be) this was a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4321) in the `0.13.*` versions. Ensuring both `react` and `react-dom` packages are both at least `0.14.0` you should be good.